# GCC error when compiling: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" with function pointer

Tags: gcc, compilation, lvalue, required

I have a C code which records a procedure address in an array

```
void* lpProcAddress[5];

typedef unsigned long (*MyFunction_TYPE) (void*);
#define MyFunctionInArray ( (MyFunction_TYPE) lpProcAddress[0] )

unsigned long AnyFunction ( void* lpPointerToAny )
{
   /* Some Code */
   return 0;
}
int main()
{
   MyFunctionInArray = 
      AnyFunction; // Displays: "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"
}
```

GCC displays "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment".
How can I fix this?
For my purpose, I could not call directly AnyFunction().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will expand to:

```
   (type)xxx = ...
```

This is not legal. However, you could use something like:

```
   * (type *)& xxx = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to `lpProcAddress[0]` directly instead of to `MyFunctionInArray`.

This should work and you can just keep it that way.

However, if you are interested in why it did not work with your define keep reading, there is a way to do that too:

What you are doing in your `#define` is cast a pointer-type to MyFunction_TYPE

1) you dont really need to cast the pointer-array to anything, you can just assign the function-pointers into its slots

2) if you really want to cast the pointer-array before assigning into it you have to cast it to a function-pointer-type (and do that before dereferencing so use parenthesis before `[0]`).

Comment: NO, assigning to lpProcAddress[0] directly works but I will also need to call the procedure from the array. If I define MyFunctionInArray without MyFunction_TYPE, I could not call it easily just by writing MyFunctionInArray(param), or I will have to define twice the same "function", once with MyFunction_TYPE, once without. It annoys me because it worked on an older version of GCC (I was obliged to change)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining lpProcAddress as void* why not just define as MyFunction_TYPE, e.g.:

```
typedef unsigned long (*MyFunction_TYPE) (void*);    

MyFunction_TYPE lpProcAddress[5];
```

Then in your main function you can just do:

```
lpProcAddress[0] = AnyFunction;
```

Without needing to care about casting.

Likewise to call the function you can then just do:

```
result = lpProcAddress[0]( some_ptr );
```

Comment: Because every array elements have not the same type, others recorded procedures may have differents return values, differents calling convention and differents parameters.

Comment: Is it feasible then to use a struct rather than an array, e.g:
`struct 
{ 
    MyFunction_TYPE1 fn1; 
    MyFunction_TYPE2 fn2;
    /*etc*/
}
`
And then possibly and array of those structs if multiple instances are needed (a union would work well also).

Comment: Yes this is feasible, I had never think to this way. But I will have to write a struct of tens of elements which matches to each functions I have already writen with my method. And a prefer have typedef next to my defines.